# Loop takes much execution time when dates duration is increased

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this function which is calculating time within 2 dates. The execution times exceeds when the duration between dates is increased causing code to throw exception.

I hope someone can help.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCalTotalOTHoursSpent] (@empCode INT, @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME) RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE  @Result INT = '0'

WHILE @StartDate < @EndDate
BEGIN
  SELECT @Result = @Result + 
    SUM(ISNULL(CAST(LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, LEFT([dbo].[fnGetOTDuration](CAST (@empCode AS NVARCHAR), @StartDate), 5)))AS INT), 0))
   SET @StartDate = @StartDate + 1;

END;

RETURN @Result
END
```

This function `[dbo].[fnGetOTDuration]` calculates time for single day. The excecution time is 1 sec for dates between 1 to 3 and then it becomes 3 seconds when dates are between 1 to 6.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh SQL Server

Comment: Could you provide some sample and expect result? and what's `fnGetOTDuration` function do in your code?

Comment: Show `fnGetOTDuration`. Your current approach is very likely doomed, though.

Comment: @D-Shih `fnGetOTDuration` This function is quite large as it contains very much possibilities on whose basis it gets overtime duration. I can show few maybe but then you'll not be able to understand table structures. Lets say I select 1st august and then this function will return 2 hours and 40 minutes and same to 2nd august and so on (lets suppose as time may vary according to date). So I am trying to add this time withing provided date duration. @Tomalak

Comment: But that's the actual reason. `fnGetOTDuration` is inefficient and calling it in a loop makes it more inefficient. It's very likely that the way your entire time calculation including the way how everything is stored must be changed if you want to make this faster.

Comment: As an interim solution you can make a table that stores the results of `fnGetOTDuration` for every employee for every day, and make a trigger or SQL job that fills this table.

Comment: @Tomalak Yeah I think so too, Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: How do you want us to help you if we do not know what your functions look like or how the logic works?